# Automatic spacing after \therefore

Tags: spacing

Would it be possible to define `\therefore` such that a certain amount of horizontal spacing will be automatically inserted (perhaps similar to `\implies`)? (Sure I can insert the space manually).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\let\oldtherefore\therefore
\renewcommand\therefore{\oldtherefore\mskip\thickmuskip}% or whatever space you want
```